# Is there a single word for "patience taken to the extreme"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Like many virtues, patience can be taken to the extreme and become detrimental.  Is there such a word for this?
Something that would fit in:

> He's too ***extremely patient*** to ever see that$20.00 that he let his
>   neighbor borrow

The closest I've been able to come up with is "ambivalence", but that does not quite fit.  "lazy" also fits, but the motivation is different.

Comment: Not sure if it quite collocates. but you might be able to say 'too long-suffering to ever expect to see.....

Comment: The concept of 'Passivity' comes to mind, with the negative connotation that action should have been taken, but was not. So, "He's too PASSIVE to ever see [...]"

Comment: Sounds saintly.

Comment: Like a **doormat**, is he?

Comment: All words that occur to me - *complaisant, forbearing, deferential*... require qualification ('too', 'overly'...) to fit your sample sentence, and so become two words.

Answer (score 1):

If the style of legend and folklore is used, there seems to be a good match for what is being said:

"He has the patience of a wooden sculpture, so he won't see the $20 that his neighbor borrowed from him."

Probably the best is the often used phrase "**the patience of Job**", which is a biblical reference that is used for one with extreme patience:

"He has the patience of Job, so he won't see the $20 that his neighbor borrowed from him."

Answer (score 1):

Probably derogatory but when used figuratively seems to describe an extreme level of patience that is detrimental.

***Doormat*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doormat)

> (noun)  1.1 a submissive person who allows others to dominate them.
>   *to put up with such treatment you must be either a saint or a doormat*

For a non-derogatory word, try ***saint*** or *saintly person*, as shown in the example sentence quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

How about **diffident**?  In other words, reluctant to challenge the neighbor, as opposed to waiting patiently because patience itself is a virtue.

Another possibility is **tolerant**.

If someone acts in a way that is detrimental to themselves, maybe a hint about the motivation is justified.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not exactly a synonym of "extremely patient", it might fit better in your sentence to use "passive."

> "He's too **passive** to ever see **the** $20.00 that he let his
>   neighbor borrow."

In this context, passive means that he is unlikely to take any action to ensure that his neighbor repays hime the $20.00 that was borrowed.